# Using PostgreSQL Aggregate ORDER BY with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query which uses PostgreSQL's syntax for using ORDER BY in an aggregate function, something like this:

```
SELECT some_agg_func(a ORDER BY b DESC) FROM table;
```

Does anyone know of anyway to do this with the sqlalchemy expression language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.aggregate_order_by):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import aggregate_order_by

expr = func.array_agg(aggregate_order_by(table.c.a, table.c.b.desc()))
stmt = select([expr])
```

Answer (score 6):

I think SqlAlchemy 1.1 has native support for `string_agg` now: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.aggregate_order_by (search the page for "func.string_agg")

Comment: Can you edit to add a link to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.aggregate_order_by and a specific example of how to use it? Then I can accept this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQLAlchemy's [compiler](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/compiler.html) extension to achieve this.  Here's an example for Postgres `string_agg` function:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnElement, _literal_as_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class string_agg(ColumnElement):
    def __init__(self, expr, separator, order_by=None):
        self.type = Text()
        self.expr = _literal_as_column(expr)
        self.separator = literal(separator)
        self.order_by = _literal_as_column(order_by)

    @property
    def _from_objects(self):
        return self.expr._from_objects

@compiles(string_agg, 'postgresql')
def compile_string_agg(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    head = 'string_agg(%s, %s' % (
        compiler.process(element.expr),
        compiler.process(element.separator)
    )
    if element.order_by is not None:
        tail = ' ORDER BY %s)' % compiler.process(element.order_by)
    else:
        tail = ')'
    return head + tail

query = session.query(string_agg(Foo.bar, ', ', order_by=Foo.bar.desc()))
# Print compiled SQL query.
print query.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
# Run the query and print result.
print query.scalar()
```

Comment: sqlalchemy 0.8 doesn't seem to have `_literal_as_column`, I solved this by using `__cause_element__` which is what `_literal_as_column` does anyway. Otherwise all good.

Comment: Yeah, I tested this on 0.7.9. I think `_literal_as_column` was renamed to `_literal_as_binds` in 0.8.

Comment: Or maybe not, as I see that `_literal_as_binds` is present in 0.7 codebase as well.